# Ansible hostvars undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a very simple play which saves vars and looks them up in hostvars.

```
- name: Set hostvars
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    var_one: "I am a"
    var_two: "test"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars['localhost']['var_one']
    - debug: var=hostvars['localhost']['var_two']
```

However, when I run this play the vars aren't defined:

```
PLAY [Set hostvars] ************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars['localhost']['var_one']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars['localhost']['var_two']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

How can I save these vars in hostvars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set host facts runtime using [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) module:

```
---
- name: Set hostvars
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact: var_one="I am a"
    - set_fact: var_two="test"
    - debug: var=hostvars['localhost']['var_one']
    - debug: var=hostvars['localhost']['var_two']
```

Quoting [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html):

*These variables will survive between plays during an Ansible run, but will not be saved across executions even if you use a fact cache.*

Answer (score 1):

This is where the difference between facts (variables bound to Ansible target hosts) and regular variables can be seen.

Variables are internally stored in `vars` structure, so you can access them with:

```
tasks:
  - debug: var=vars['var_one']
  - debug: var=vars['var_two']
```

Facts, on the other hand are stored in `hostvars`.

---

In either case, unless you were referring to a variable name with a dynamic name, or a fact bound to another host than the one executing the task, you can simply use the variable/fact name by using its name:

```
tasks:
  - debug: var=var_one
  - debug: var=var_two
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using

> msg=

instead of var=. As per help of debug module

```
var - A variable name to debug. Mutually exclusive with the 'msg' option.
```

---

```
- name: Set hostvars
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    var_one: I am a
    var_two: est
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=hostvars['localhost']['var_one']
    - debug: msg=hostvars['localhost']['var_two']
...



PLAY [Set hostvars] ************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "hostvars['localhost']['var_one']"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "hostvars['localhost']['var_two']"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: This is outrageously wrong. OP wants to print variable **values**. This answer suggests to (and shows how to) print fixed strings `hostvars['localhost']['var_one']` and `hostvars['localhost']['var_one']`.